# Выборка из двух таблиц mysql (join, массив)

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы (в одной статьи, в другой категории). В первой в поле `category` указаны `id` от второй, но главное что указаны в виде `"1,3,7,9"`. Тоесть можно сказать что массив(массив преобразован в строку`(implode)`). Одна статья может находится в нескольких категориях.
Структуры таблиц(примерно):

```
articles (id, name, category) 
category (id, name)
```

Запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` 
INNER JoIN `category`
ON category.id IN (articles.category)
```

ничего не выбирает, точнее выбирает только первую категорию(id=1).
А вот если указать в таком варианте

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` 
INNER JoIN `category`
ON category.id IN (1,3,7,9)
```

то все выбирает. Но я не могу это реализовать на PHP, так как заранее категории неизвестны. А делать доп запросы не хочу. Хотелось бы все в одном.

Мне надо чтобы выбрались статьи, где вместо `id` категорий были их наименования. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вот это решит Вашеу проблему.

```sql
SELECT articles.* FROM articles
JOIN categories c ON FIND_IN_SET(categories.id, articles.category)>0
WHERE categories .name IN ('[имя категории 1]', '[имя категории 2]', '[имя категории 3]');
```